# jQuery only getting first radio button value

Tags: jquery, radio-button, radio-group

I've searched everywhere, still not working. 
I've got this radio group:

```js
var tipo = jQuery("input[name=tipo]:checked").val();

  teste.click(function(){
    console.log(tipo);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divLabel"><label for="tipo">Tipo:</label></div>
  <div class="divInput">
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="0" id="tipo_1" class="tipo" checked>
      Diárias
      <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="1" id="tipo_2" class="tipo">
      Indenização de Campo
</div>
```

But var **tipo**  doesn't get the current value when I change radio button option. It always shows only value **0**.

What am I missing?

Comment: Getting `0` as the variable is not getting updated after page load. Get checked value in the click handler i.e. `teste.click(function(){ tipo = jQuery("input[name=tipo]:checked").val();
        alert(tipo);
    });` and I recommend using `change` handler

Comment: Yes, that was it. Now I got it! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio][name=tipo]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
          alert(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divLabel"><label for="tipo">Tipo:</label></div>
    <div class="divInput">
       <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="0" id="tipo_1" class="tipo" checked>Diárias
      <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="1" id="tipo_2" class="tipo">Indenização de Campo
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```