# Best way to render radio buttons as toggle-able buttons in a web form

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like my radio buttons on a form to look like toggle-able HTML buttons, like [these Bootstrap examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/). Using Flask, Bootstrap, and jinja2, I've been able to convert my radio buttons to "buttons". This part of my form currently looks like this:

```
{{ form.setting.label }}<br>           
{% for subfield in form.setting %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ subfield(class_="no_rad") }}</td>
        <td>{{ subfield.label(class_="btn btn-primary") }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}<br>
```

Here, subfield would be the radio button itself. The `class_="no_rad"` assigns a CSS class I created with `display: none;`. With the same method, `subfield.label` gets assigned a Bootstrap CSS class that makes it look like a button. The buttons are "selectable" (they have data), however:

- I would like for it to appear that the button is toggled when clicked
- I would like the buttons to be unselected if re-clicked (unlike typical radio buttons)

I understand this might require Jquery but I don't know where to start.

Comment: You could start by adding a `.on('click', fnWhenClicked)` to do something when the button is clicked. You should be able to use JQuery to get a reference to the button. Whatever you put in that fnWhenClicked is up to you.

Comment: @user3832673 I tried to addClass but this is not working: 
https://gist.github.com/bfbarry/b45ff4b718d35c49ee2dee5f82231580

Comment: why don't you add a global flag, which inverts itself after each click of button and check for flag before all code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out, for the *most* part, how to accomplish what I want. Without manually coded Jquery, I just had to integrate more bootstrap functionality (following the examples linked in my question) like so:

an ugly clump of src tags in base.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and the Bootstrap/jinja2 medley in the page being displayed:

```
{{ form.setting.label }}<br>           
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    {% for subfield in form.setting %}
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ subfield}} {{ subfield.label(style="cursor:pointer;") }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}<br> 
    {% for error in form.setting.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The buttons, when clicked, look activated. I say for the *most* part because there are some weird rendering features:

- I have to manually input `style="cursor:pointer;"` to `subfield.label` because otherwise the cursor will be the default one when hovering over the button's label, and slightly around that label will default to the button's pointer cursor.
- The buttons themselves are awkwardly taller than they should be. This can be fixed with CSS but I'm not sure why this happens.
- Part of my form is dynamic and updates based on radio button values using jquery. With these Bootstrap styles however, my script is only detecting when the first button in the div gets clicked and not the others. Edit: I've solved this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558095/jquery-only-getting-first-radio-button-value)